# Sending email through Gmail with django works with send_mail but not with EmailMultiAlternatives and html

Tags: django, email, gmail

I want to send an email using gmail's smtp sever. I have correctly set up my settings variables for gmail and send_mail() workls as it should. But when I am trying to send an email through EmailMultiAlternatives send function, it will hang and not send. My code for the email is the following.

```
d = Context(dict(users=users, frontdesk={'user': frontdesk, 'password': password}))
htmly = get_template('email.html')
subject, from_email, to = 'Account Info', 'myemail@gmail.com', ' myemail@gmail.com'
html_content = htmly.render(d)
text_content = "This is text content"
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, 'text/html')
print 'Trying to send email...'
msg.send()
```

This won't work but `send_mail(subject, text_content, 'myemail@gmail.com', 'myemail@gmail.com')` will work.

My settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my-password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Am I doing something wrong?Can I use send_mail to send html emails? I am using django 1.6.5.

Comment: Are you sure that users, frontdesk, password etc are correct? also I would not use frontdesk twice.
Problem seems to be the template and Context part, additionally try the render_to_string:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut

Comment: what do you mean by correct, If I use the python smtpd module for development it works fine.

Comment: I mean are the user, frontdesk vars defined? send_mail seems to work because you are using a "This is a text content" message which does not use any of the vars, so my first suggestion is to debug the vars.

Comment: The problem was that I had to activate Imap on my gmail account. Once this was done it sent the email normally. Thank you for your time